# strtotime() not working for some reason

Tags: php, date

I have a string which is in the format: dd/mm/yy

e.g. 29/03/14

But when I print it using date() I get a completely different date!

What am I missing?

```
$endDate = "29/03/14";
echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime( $endDate ));
```

- 1st January, 1970

I even tried:

```
echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime( trim($endDate) ));
```

With no luck!

I am reading $endDate from a text file

What I am trying to do is find out if it is the last day of the month...

i.e. Current month is 03 - March has 31 days
The day of month in file is 29 
This is not the last day of the month

Comment: Are you fetching the date from db? Is it of varchar type ?

Comment: The date is coming from a file - I'm reading plain text from a file and trying to convert it into a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format isn't recognized by `strtotime()`. Use DateTime class instead:

```
$dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $str);
echo $dateObj->format('jS F, Y');
```

Output:

```
29th March, 2014
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/133569)

---

> What I am trying to do is find out if it is the last day of the month...

For that, you just have to check if the given date is the same as the last day of the month (which can be obtained with `t` format character)

```
$str = '29/03/14';
$dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $str);

if ($dateObj->format('d') == $dateObj->format('t')) {
    echo 'Given date is the last day of the month';
}
```

Comment: I need to know the last day of the month from the month that is in the date from the file...

Comment: DateTime::createFromFormat() will not work in php5.2

Comment: @php-b-grader: PHP 5.2 was released ages ago. You should upgrade to a more recent PHP version.

Comment: great solution! it's old so get a new one... I'm not looking for a new one, I'm looking for a solution that works on the platform I have been provided

Answer (score 2):

Your date format is not valid.

Check the **[Date Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)**

You might consider using `date_create_from_format('d/m/y','29/03/14');` and work with the **DateTime** object.

Answer (score 2):

Use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', '29/03/14');
echo $date->format("jS F, Y");
```

For getting the last day

```
echo $date->format('t');
```